# is there a way to get git-log to name commits the way git-show-branch does?

Tags: git

`git show-branch` formats commits in a way that easy to type, without cutting and pasting commit shas

```
 + [head~7] wip
 + [head~8] wip
 + [head~9] wip
 + [head~10] wip
 + [head~11] wip
 + [head~12] wip
```

`git log` on the other hand looks like this:

```
* 6e3d209 wip
* 993cf20 wip
* 4e7cf9d wip
* dd2a768 wip
* bf0d100 wip
```

Is there any way to get `git log` to print names like `head~10` for commits?

Answer (score 1):

While it not exactly what you requested, you can try passing `-g`/`--walk-reflogs` to `git log`. This will cause `git log` to display your *reflog* entries instead of the ancestry chain of a commit. Alternatively, you can use `git reflog` directly if you don't care about customizing the formatting. As long as the commit you care about was checked-out recently, this will show you a convenient-to-type name for it as a reflog entry (`HEAD@{N}`).

Running either `git log -g --oneline` or `git reflog` will produce an output that looks something like the following:

```
8096059 (HEAD -> feat/foo) HEAD@{0}: commit: wip
51db69a HEAD@{1}: commit: wip
83c8976 HEAD@{2}: commit: wip
078596e HEAD@{3}: commit: wip
8679120 HEAD@{4}: commit: wip
48fb2e1 HEAD@{5}: commit: wip
01b665c (origin/master, master) HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from master to feat/foo
01b665c (origin/master, master) HEAD@{7}: commit: wip
40cbb0b HEAD@{8}: merge feat/bar: wip
5c49f70 HEAD@{9}: checkout: moving from feat/bar to master
40cbb0b HEAD@{10}: commit: wip
```

From this you can, for example, easily pick out `HEAD@{4}` as a shorthand for the commit `8679120`.